# How can we use custom CSS and JavaScript in new Developer portal (Azure) - Migration from Deprecated to new Developer Portal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, migration

I am not very much familiar with Azure. I want to migrate deprecated portal to the new portal but with the old design which we are using in deprecated portal because it is client requirement.

So please help me on this. I want to use the same design with custom html, CSS and JavaScript logic(s).

Comment: which developer portal are you talking about ? APIM ?

Comment: @Thomas Yes API Management.

Comment: have you check the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal-customize ? looks like you can customize the portal, not sure what s your question ?

Comment: @Thomas I have created the pages with my own css and javascript logic(s) in deprecated portal and now my client requirement is that he wants the same design/look in new portal. I hope you understand my concern now.

Comment: I have this same issue. I cannot find a meaningful way to customize the Developer Portal API UI with code. All MS provides is a wyziwyg that adds little value